# Configure kubernetes cluster to use OpenID Connect Authentication

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect

Configured my kubernetes cluster to use OpenID Connect Authentication . i'm getting the error as "error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)" . I have

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: admin-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: admin-binding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: krishnavamsi@gmail.com
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin-role
```

Below is the part of the configuration that i have added.

```
users:
- name: krishnavamsi@gmail.com
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        client-id: XXXXXX
        client-secret: YYYYYYYYYY
        id-token: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
        idp-issuer-url: https://accounts.google.com
        refresh-token: PPPPPPPPPPPPP
      name:oidc
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62488189/edit) and fix the formatting, and while there, be sure to include the values for [`--oidc-issuer-url=`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#configuring-the-api-server) (and the rest) that you added to your apiservers

Comment: Hi, what version of k8s are You using?

Comment: version of k8s - 1.17.1

Answer (score 1):

I now got the issue resolved . This step was missing.

sed -i "/- kube-apiserver/a\    - --oidc-issuer-url=https://accounts.google.com\n    - --oidc-username-claim=email\n    - --oidc-client-id=[YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID]" /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml on master before.